# Interpretation of this Hamiltonian

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space, coupled-oscillators

I'm studying a system with the following Hamiltonian $$ H = \frac{1}{2}P^TAP + \frac{1}{2}Q^T B Q$$ where $P,Q$ are canonical variables (4-vectors) and $A,B$ matrices such that $A = A^\dagger$ and $B = B^\dagger$.
I notice that $H$ could be written as $$H = \langle P, AP \rangle + \langle Q, BQ \rangle $$
where the $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the usual inner product of $M^4$, thus are two quadratic forms.
What can we say about the system?
Is this a significant form?

Comment: Suggestion to post (v2): Replace $\dagger$ with $T$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, assuming that $A$ is positive definite, you can always revert to the case $A=1$ by a canonical transformation:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2}P^TP+\frac{1}{2}Q^TBQ
$$
Now you just need to apply the spectral theorem and revert to the case $B$ is diagonal:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2}P^TP+\sum \frac{1}{2}Q_kB_kQ_k
$$
the problem is therefore integrable.

In the general, the normal form of quadratic Hamiltonians (classification and reduction) is given in Appendix 6 of Arnold's *Mathematical Method of Classical Mechanics*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was wondering by what you understand the problem is integrable. Is the second $H$ you wrote known?

Comment: Yes, they are just independent harmonic/unstable oscillators (depending on the signs of $B_k$). The action variables are $I_k = \frac{\sqrt{|B_k|}}{2}(P_k^2+B_kQ_k)$. If some the the $B_k$ are equal, the system is even super integrable and maximally integrable when all are equal.